# Replace function and its derivatives by zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions

If I try to replace the function `u0` and its derivatives by zero in the following examplary expression

```
expr = t HeavisideTheta[0.174 +φ] - 1651.2 u0[t, φ] + 3293.841 t Derivative[0, 1][u0][t, φ];
expr/.u0->(0&)
(*0. + t HeavisideTheta[0.174 + φ]*)
```

Mathematica gives an output `0.+...`.

My question: How can I avoid this zero part `0.+` in the output(without using `Chop`) ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you just add another replacement rule?

```
expr /. u0 -> (0&) /. 0. -> 0
```

> t HeavisideTheta[0.174 + φ]

Comment: Thanks, unbelievable simple trick `/.0. -> 0`, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try also this:

```
Map[Rationalize, expr, Infinity] /. u0 -> (0 &) // N

(* t HeavisideTheta[0.174 + φ]  *)
```

Comment: Thanks! `expr /. u0 -> (0 &) // Rationalize` works too!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Yes, this your version is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will cause other problem, but the following does work for your example:

```
Clear@u0
u0 /: u0[__] number_Real := 0
Derivative[__][u0] ^:= u0
expr
(* t HeavisideTheta[0.174 + φ] *)
```

Comment: @xzcd Thanks, your first solution (comment `SetPrecision[expr, Infinity] /. u0 -> (0 &)` )  seems to be more reliable because it also solves the case `expr=t HeavisideTheta[a + \[CurlyPhi]] - b u0[t, \[CurlyPhi]] + 
 c t Derivative[0, 1][u0][t, \[CurlyPhi]]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I removed that one because I think that method is somewhat similar to the `Chop` method. (It changes the numbers inside `expr`, too. ) To handle the new added example, you can again add a `/. u0 -> (0 &)` at the end of `expr`.